# SQL returning auto-incremented ID

Tags: sql, return, auto-increment

I'm trying to pick up SQL and am using it in conjuction with ASP Classic. I'm currently inserting into a database but have come across a problem, the insertion works fine but I want to be able to set a variable to be the value of the ID that is generated as a result of the insertion (it's an auto-incrememnting field so a new ID is created every time I insert) and then return the value of this variable to the user.
Here's what I've currently got: (QuestionID is the auto-incremementing ID)

```
     set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
     rs.Open "Select * from Questions", conn
     sql="DECLARE @id int"     
     sql=sql & "INSERT INTO Questions(QuestionText, QuestionType)"
     sql=sql & " VALUES "
     sql=sql & "@id = Inserted.QuestionID;"
     sql=sql & "('" & qtext & "',"
     sql=sql & "'" & "checkbox" & "')"
     Response.Write("<br/>" & @id & "<br/>" )

     on error resume next
     conn.Execute sql,recaffected
     if err<>0 then
     Response.Write("An Error Has Occured")
     else
     Response.Write("Data Added")
     end if
     conn.close
```

Any help?
(again sorry if this is a stupid question, i'm new to this stuff)

Answer (score 1):

In the same query just add at the end.

```
select @@identity as ID
```

hit the books about this global variable and some nice function do similar thing.

p.s. your app is prone to sql inject attack

Comment: Sorry to be annoying but could you give me some example code that would return this value via response.write()?
P.s I know, i'm still learning, give me a break ;)

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you will prefer the result of `scope_identity()`, not `@@identity`. They are both very similar, however `scope_identity()` is restricted to the current session *and* scope.

Conversely, `@@identity` is only restricted to the current session. This means it could potentially return the identity value of a row inserted by a DML trigger that you may or may not know exists.

It's an edge case, to be sure, but you are almost always better off with `scope_identity()`.

Comment: how would I set scope_identitiy() to be the value of a variable?

Comment: See Nagaraj S's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` or `@@identity`

```
SET @id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
      RETURN  @id
```

---

```
string id = cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value.ToString() ;
Response.Write("data added ID = " +  id);
```